# JSF 2.0 project Structure

Tags: java, jsf-2, vs-web-application-project

We are creating a new project using jsf2.0, richfaces 4.0, jjdk 6 and tomcat 7.0
     I want to know the standard way of creating project. I mean folder structure. Any sample application or book or link will be a great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I participated once in a project, which had Spring 3.5, JSF 1.2 and [ICEFaces](http://www.icefaces.org/) 1.8, was running on JDK6 and everything was deployed to Tomcat 6.0 - similar situation to yours. We used [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as a project management tool.

Very flexible and comfortable. You could also consider using ICEFaces instead of RichFaces.

Answer (score 2):

Maven uses a best practice approach for project folders. Even when you do not plan to build with maven, have a look at their structures:

- [Maven: Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)